# Facebook Authentication Problems with Ngrok and Meteor

Tags: facebook, meteor, ngrok

I'm trying to test my meteor app, which uses Facebook-based login integration, locally rather than deploy it continuously. To do this, I've set up ngrok to tunnel to my localhost on port 3000, where my local meteor server is deployed. The server is running with no problem and I've added the Facebook keys to the site. I'm also using the `accounts-base`, `accounts-ui`, and `accounts-facebook` packages. When I click on  `Sign in with Facebook` button at the top of the page, however, I get the following error message:

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

Has anybody else had this problem or has an idea for a fix for it?

Thanks,

Matthew

Answer (score 0):

This is because you haven't added your app domain to your Facebook App Settings. And as far I as I know, Facebook does not accept ngrok.io as a valid app domain.

You'll need to deploy your app to your domain, add your domain to Facebook App Settings and things should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me. Hope it helps!

**From your [app dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/)**

Products -> FB Login Settings -> add your ngrok url to both:

- Valid OAuth Redirect URIs
- Allowed Domains for the JavaScript SDK

Click on Save changes